# trackCart not working in MC Collect Code

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations, behavioral-triggers

We have the following snippet in order to track cart in our website using the MC Collect Code:

```
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://REMOVED.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
_etmc.push(['setOrgId', 'REMOVED']);

_etmc.push(['trackCart', {
    'cart': [
        {
            'item': 'A',
            'quantity':  '5',
            'price': '1',
            'unique_id': '1'
        },
        {
            'item': 'A',
            'quantity':  '5 ,
            'price': '1' ,
            'unique_id': '2'
        }
    ]
}]);
</script>
</body>
```

However, when going to the Status tab in email recommendations Track Cart Activity remains 0.

Please help what is wrong the code above,
Thanks
Barak

Comment: Have you verified that items added to cart actually are in your catalogue?

Comment: Hi Lukas, yes I have double checked that. Also when using Chrome network tool, no payload is being sent as far as I can tell. So I don't believe it reaches this step where items are being validated aginst the catalogue.

Comment: what is the status in the dev console on your browser? 200? 403?  have you created a recommendation yet?

Comment: It was 200 for the collect.js file. Did not try to create a recommendation since the collect not working.

Answer (score 0):

please add this also

_etmc.push(['setUserInfo', {'email': 'INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID'}]);